# Does not get the DOM elements inside of iframe until I inspect element to that particular tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, chatbot

I have the below webpage which embeds a chatbot window into it.
https://lippert-web.firebaseapp.com/

I'm trying to change the bot name under a certain condition(for which I'm using an event of the bot framework).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Web Channel</title>
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var AvaamoChatBot = function (t) {
        function o(t, o) {
          var n = document.createElement("script");
          n.setAttribute("src", t),
            n.setAttribute("id", "avm-web-channel"),
            (n.onload = o),
            document.body.appendChild(n);
        }
        return (
          (this.options = t || {}),
          (this.load = function (t) {
            o(this.options.url, function () {
              window.Avaamo.addFrame(),
                t && "function" == typeof t && t(window.Avaamo);
            });
          }),
          this
        );
      };
      var chatBox = new AvaamoChatBot({
        url:
          "https://c10.avaamo.com/web_channels/t-dae9bf37-e942-44ac-bb42-3804c81bde36?action=demo&banner=true&banner_text=+&banner_title=This+is+how+the+chat+agent+shows+up&controller=web_channels&demo=true&theme=avm-messenger",
      });
      chatBox.load(function (avaamo) {
        avaamo.onBotMessage = (message) => {
          if(message.content && message.content.toLowerCase().includes("sure thing, i’ll get you right") && message.conversation_uuid){
            console.log("Live Agent Transfer");
            document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="name-"]').forEach(botName=>{
              botName.innerHTML = "Live Agent";
            });
          }
          else if(((message.content && message.content.toLowerCase().includes("i'm sorry, but no customer care specialist") ||(avaamo.content_type == "default_card" && avaamo.attachments.default_card.description.toLowerCase().includes("thanks for chatting with us today"))) && message.conversation_uuid)){
            console.log("Out Of Live Agent");
            document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="name-"]').forEach(botName=>{
              botName.innerHTML = "Valerie";
            });
          }
        };
      });
      //chec
      // if(!window.Avaamo){
      //   setTimeout(function (){
      //     Avaamo.welcomeNotification.open();
      //   },1000)
      // }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here I'm using the below code to change the innerHtml, which doesn't seems to be working:

```
document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="name-"]').forEach(botName=>{
              botName.innerHTML = "Valerie";
            });
```

Also when I inspect element, open the bot window and 1st try the code, I get no result.

```
document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="name-"]')
```

But then I inspect into botname element, and try it works.

Just want to understand the why is this happening.

[image: Step1]
[image: Step 2]
[image: Step 3]

Comment: It's been a very long time since I've had anything to do with this, but from what I remember, it's just not allowed because it's a security issue. You can't do much with content from other websites. So you can't inspect and manipulate the DOM of an iframe whose content is from another website. The browser can, but your code can't.

Comment: @AshleyMiller is there a workaround for this? By replacing the content using ::before